# How do I tell RubyMine the file type when the file has no extension?

Tags: rubymine

This seems like it should be easy.

I'm creating a CLI command gem, so the command is in `bin/gem_name` which has no `.rb` extension. When I try to edit that file in RubyMine, it doesn't give it a language mode (sorry, don't know the proper term) to make syntax highlighting and other niftyness in RubyMine work.

How can I tell RubyMine that this is, in fact, a Ruby file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to tell RubyMine that a file is of a particular type:

1. Begin the command file with a hashbang line that RubyMine recognizes as being Ruby. I don't know what exactly it recognizes, but all of the scripts that gems put in to my bin dir begin with

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env ruby
   ```

   and when I make a new script which begins with that line RubyMine also recognizes it as being Ruby (even before I open it). I did notice that when I had a file without this line and then added it I had to quit and restart RubyMine for it to take effect.
2. Just open the file in RubyMine. When I open a file that RubyMine doesn't recognize, it asks me what type it is and remembers what I tell it.
3. Register the file manually:

   - Go to Preferences -> IDE Settings -> File Types
   - Under File Types, select "Ruby files"
   - Under Registered Patterns, add a new pattern that matches `gem_name`

   It would be painful to have to do this for a lot of files, but it might be useful in some cases.

I'm surprised that method 2 didn't work for you already. Maybe you told RubyMine that the file was a text file. Check the Text file type in the File types preferences to be sure your file isn't registered as text.

Comment: I'm not sure why it didn't work for me, either. I created the gem with `bundle gem NAME` before I launched RubyMine on it, so it was rather surprising it didn't pick up the type from #2 above.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the filename in the project view.
2. Select "Associate with File Type..."
3. Select "Ruby"