# Is it possible to set language on a per file basis in RubyMine?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, jetbrains-ide, rubymine

I have found two questions, but they received answers saying to set a default: one for [the file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315342/rubymine-change-code-language), and the other for [the specific file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547163/how-do-i-tell-rubymine-the-file-type-when-the-file-has-no-extension?rq=1).

It feels implied by those answers that this was impossible at the time to specify language with ad hoc, file-by-file specificity.

Is it possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: You have to associate it (file) with specific File Type (based on file name/extension pattern) or via shebang. You cannot use "Open as" or chanage language on the fly -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113835

Comment: Are these files part of your project ? or scratch files ?

Comment: It would be useful for either case. Right now I am specifically looking at files already in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to accidentally do something like this and was trying to figure out how to undo it. RubyMine had somehow put a specific filename in the file name pattern list. This might be close enough to what this question was asking.

[image: rubymine settings with auto-detect with specific filename]